# No matter what my feedback string says .find will go into the if statement

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and coding in general and I am making my midterm for my college class. While writing the code, I made a string called feedback, which by default is set to nothing. When I get an error in my sets, it adds an error message to my feedback string. However, when I run the program, there are no errors happening in the sets. Despite there being no errors, my feedback.find("ERROR:") if statement will always be entered, even though feedback is still blank.

Here is my main cpp code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <dos.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "PlayerClass.h"
#include "Archer.h"
#include "Wizard.h"
#include "Knight.h"
#include "Cleric.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Player myPlayer;

    do
    {
        string PlayerChoice;
        cout << "Choose which class you want (wizard, archer, knight, cleric): ";
        cin >> PlayerChoice;

        if (PlayerChoice == "wizard")
        {
            myPlayer.PlayerSetClass(1);
            break;
        }
        else if (PlayerChoice == "archer")
        {
            myPlayer.PlayerSetClass(4);
            break;
        }
        else if (PlayerChoice == "knight")
        {
            myPlayer.PlayerSetClass(2);
            break;
        }
        else if (PlayerChoice == "cleric")
        {
            myPlayer.PlayerSetClass(3);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            string feedback2 = "";
            feedback2 += "\nERROR: PLEASE ENTER CHARACTER SPELLED CORRECTLY AND NO UPPERCASE. \n";
            cout << feedback2;
        }
    } 
    while (true);

    myPlayer.PrintStats();

    cout << "=================================================" << endl << "=================================================" << endl;

    const int ArraySize = 5;


    //Makes the 5 enemy AI.
    Player EnemyPlayers[ArraySize + 1];

    for (int cntr = 1; cntr <= ArraySize; cntr++)
    {
        EnemyPlayers[cntr].SetClass();

        Coord temp;
        temp.x = rand() % 79;
        temp.y = rand() % 20;
        EnemyPlayers[cntr].SetPosition(temp);

        if (EnemyPlayers[cntr].feedback.find("ERROR:")) //Here it is always entering the if statemen
        {
            cout << "\n\n" << EnemyPlayers->feedback << "\n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << EnemyPlayers[cntr].GetName() << "("<<EnemyPlayers[cntr].GetPosition().x << "," << EnemyPlayers[cntr].GetPosition().y << ")" << " -- Health: " << EnemyPlayers[cntr].GetHealth() << "\n";
        }

        
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

My header file (the only one actually being used):

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <dos.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

enum weapon { BOW, WAND, SWORD, STAFF, NONE };

struct Coord
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

class Player
{
    private:
        string name;
        int health;
        int armor;
        int strength;
        int stamina;
        int experience;
        bool passive;
        weapon weapons;

        Coord position;

    public:

        string feedback;

        Player();
        Player(weapon tWeapon);

        string GetName();
        string SetName(string tName);

        int GetHealth();
        string SetHealth(int tHealth);

        int GetArmor();
        string SetArmor(int tArmor);

        int GetStrength();
        string SetStrength(int tStrength);

        int GetStamina();
        string SetStamina(int tStamina);

        int GetExperience();
        string SetExperience(int tExperience);

        bool GetPassive();
        string SetPassive(bool tPassive);

        void SetPosition(Coord tPosition);
        Coord GetPosition();
        
        bool IsCollision(Player tPlayer);

        void SetClass();
        void PlayerSetClass(int tNumber);

        virtual void PrintStats();
        virtual void Attacked(int tStrength, int tExperience);
};
```

And my other cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dos.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "PlayerClass.h"


Player::Player()
{
    name = "Player";
    health;
    armor;
    strength;
    stamina;
    experience;
    passive;
    weapons = BOW;
    feedback = "";
    position.x = 20;
    position.y = 20;
}

Player::Player(weapon tWeapon)
{
    Player();
    weapons = tWeapon;
}

string Player::GetName()
{
    return name;
}

string Player::SetName(string tName)
{
    name = tName;
    return "Ok";
}

int Player::GetHealth()
{
    return health;
}

string Player::SetHealth(int tHealth)
{
    if (tHealth > 0 && tHealth <= 100)
    {
        string strResponse = "HEALTH SET CORRECTLY ";
        feedback += strResponse;
        health = tHealth;
        return strResponse;
    }
    else
    {
        health = 100;
        string strResponse = "ERROR: COULD NOT SET HEALTH. HEALTH MUST BE BETWEEN 1 AND 100.";
        feedback += strResponse;
        return strResponse;
    }
}

int Player::GetStrength()
{
    return strength;
}

string Player::SetStrength(int tStrength)
{
    if (tStrength >= 0 && tStrength <= 100)
    {
        string strResponse = "STRENGTH SET CORRECTLY ";
        feedback += strResponse;
        strength = tStrength;
        return strResponse;
    }
    else
    {
        strength = 0;
        string strResponse = "ERROR: COULD NOT SET STAMINA. STRENGTH MUST BE BETWEEN 0 AND 100.";
        feedback += strResponse;
        return strResponse;
    }
}

int Player::GetStamina()
{
    return stamina;
}

string Player::SetStamina(int tStamina)
{
    if (tStamina >= 0 && tStamina <= 100)
    {
        string strResponse = "STAMINA SET CORRECTLY ";
        feedback += strResponse;
        stamina = tStamina;
        return strResponse;
    }
    else
    {
        stamina = 0;
        string strResponse = "ERROR: COULD NOT SET STAMINA. STAMINA MUST BE BETWEEN 0 AND 100.";
        feedback += strResponse;
        return strResponse;
    }
}

int Player::GetExperience()
{
    return experience;
}

string Player::SetExperience(int tExperience)
{
    if (tExperience >= 0 && tExperience <= 100)
    {
        string strResponse = "EXPERIENCE SET CORRECTLY ";
        feedback += strResponse;
        experience = tExperience;
        return strResponse;
    }
    else
    {
        experience = 0;
        string strResponse = "ERROR: COULD NOT SET EXPERIENCE. EXPERIENCE MUST BE BETWEEN 0 AND 100.";
        feedback += strResponse;
        return strResponse;
    }
}

bool Player::GetPassive()
{
    if (passive == true)
    {
        feedback += "YOUR PASSIVE IS ACTIVE. ";
    }
    else
    {
        feedback += "YOUR PASSIVE IS INACTIVE.  ";
    }
    return passive;
}

string Player::SetPassive(bool tPassive)
{
    string strResponse = "Ok";
    passive = tPassive;
    return strResponse;
}

string Player::SetArmor(int tArmor)
{
    if (tArmor > 0 && tArmor <= 100)
    {
        string strResponse = "ARMOR SET CORRECTLY ";
        feedback += strResponse;
        armor = tArmor;
        return strResponse;
    }
    else
    {
        armor = 0;
        string strResponse = "ERROR: SET ARMOR COULD NOT BE COMPLETED, ARMOR MUST BE SET BETWEEN 0 AND 100.";
        feedback += strResponse;
        return strResponse;
    }
}

int Player::GetArmor() 
{
    return armor;
}

void Player::SetPosition(Coord tPosition)
{
    if ((tPosition.x >= 0 && tPosition.x <= 80) && (tPosition.y >= 0 && tPosition.y <= 20))
    {
        position = tPosition;
    }
    else
    {
        feedback += "\nERROR: COORDINATE IS OFF OUR MAPPING SYSTEM (80x20)";
    }
}

Coord Player::GetPosition()
{
    return position;
}

bool Player::IsCollision(Player tPlayer)
{
    bool tCollision = false;

    if (position.x == tPlayer.GetPosition().x && position.y == tPlayer.GetPosition().y)
    {
        tCollision = true;
    }

    return tCollision;
}

void Player::PrintStats()
{
    cout << "Your name is: " << GetName() << endl;
    cout << "Your health is: " << GetHealth() << endl;
    cout << "Your strength is: " << GetStrength() << endl;
    cout << "Your stamina is: " << GetStamina() << endl;
    cout << "Your experience is: " << GetExperience() << endl;
    cout << "Your passive is: " << GetPassive() << endl;
    cout << "Your armor is: " << GetArmor() << endl;

    string strWeapon = "";

    if (weapons == weapon::BOW)
    {
        strWeapon = "bow.";
    }
    else if (weapons == weapon::WAND)
    {
        strWeapon = "wand.";
    }
    else if (weapons == weapon::SWORD)
    {
        strWeapon = "sword.";
    }
    else if (weapons == weapon::STAFF)
    {
        strWeapon = "staff.";
    }
    cout << "Your weapon is a " << strWeapon << endl;

    cout << feedback << endl;
}

void Player::Attacked(int tStrength, int tExperience)
{
    int Damage = tStrength * (tExperience / 100);
    SetHealth(GetHealth() - Damage);
    cout << GetName() << " was attacked";
}

void Player::SetClass()
{
    int tNumber = (rand() % 4) + 1;
    if (tNumber == 1)
    {
        SetName("Wizard");
        SetHealth(100);
        SetStrength(10);
        SetStamina(40);
        SetExperience(10);
        SetPassive(true);
        SetArmor(35);
        weapons = WAND;
    }
    if (tNumber == 2)
    {
        SetName("Knight");
        SetHealth(100);
        SetStrength(50);
        SetStamina(35);
        SetExperience(0);
        SetPassive(true);
        SetArmor(40);
        weapons = SWORD;
    }
    if (tNumber == 3)
    {
        SetName("Cleric");
        SetHealth(80);
        SetStrength(30);
        SetStamina(80);
        SetExperience(40);
        SetPassive(true);
        SetArmor(20);
        weapons = STAFF;
    }
    if (tNumber == 4)
    {
        SetName("Archer");
        SetHealth(60);
        SetStrength(30);
        SetStamina(70);
        SetExperience(40);
        SetPassive(true);
        SetArmor(40);
        weapons = BOW;
    }
    else if (tNumber >= 5)
    {
        feedback += "ERROR: ENEMY CLASS COULD NOT BE SET.";
    }
}

void Player::PlayerSetClass(int tNumber)
{
    if (tNumber == 1)
    {
        SetName("Player Wizard");
        SetHealth(100);
        SetStrength(10);
        SetStamina(40);
        SetExperience(10);
        SetPassive(true);
        SetArmor(35);
        weapons = WAND;
    }
    if (tNumber == 2)
    {
        SetName("Player Knight");
        SetHealth(100);
        SetStrength(50);
        SetStamina(35);
        SetExperience(0);
        SetPassive(true);
        SetArmor(40);
        weapons = SWORD;
    }
    if (tNumber == 3)
    {
        SetName("Player Cleric");
        SetHealth(80);
        SetStrength(30);
        SetStamina(80);
        SetExperience(40);
        SetPassive(true);
        SetArmor(20);
        weapons = STAFF;
    }
    if (tNumber == 4)
    {
        SetName("Player Archer");
        SetHealth(60);
        SetStrength(30);
        SetStamina(70);
        SetExperience(40);
        SetPassive(true);
        SetArmor(40);
        weapons = BOW;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like there's a whole lot of code here that doesn't directly have to do with your feedback message and it makes it hard to tell what's happening. Can you try to pare this down to a minimal complete example that demonstrates the issue you're having with as little other code as possible?

Comment: That being said, it seems like you don't understand what exactly `find` is returning. `if (EnemyPlayers[cntr].feedback.find("ERROR:")) ` `find` returns `std::string::npos`, [which is](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) `-1`, if it doesn't find the substring. `if(-1)` is still `true` because `-1` is not `0`.

Comment: @NathanPierson it isnt `-1`. iirc it is defined via `-1` but its an unsigned

Comment: Good catch, yes. It still evaluates to `true` when converted to a `bool`.

Comment: __Code minimizing tips:__ The player's character is not needed. Get rid of the first part of `main()`. You need only one enemy; reduce `Player EnemyPlayers[ArraySize + 1];` to `Player EnemyPlayer;`, then proceed directly to the `if` statement you asked about. Even better, instead of two lines with output (and an `if` statement choosing between them), simplify to a single line with output, as in `std::cout << "Result of find is truth? " << EnemyPlayers[cntr].feedback.find("ERROR:") << '\n';`. That gets you down to two lines plus a class definition, a nice [mre].

Comment: please edit your post and remove unused details and text to simplify your question and pay attention to focus on your main problem and explain more about it to help others answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

`std::string::find` does not return `true` or `false`. Instead it returns the index at which the substring was found. Hence this is wrong:

```
if (EnemyPlayers[cntr].feedback.find("ERROR:"))
```

Only when the string starts with `"ERROR:"` and `find` returns `0` the condition evaluates to `false`. But there is a `\n` at the front, so this doesn't happen.

When the substring cannot be found `find` returns `std::string::npos`. The right way to see if the substring was found is:

```
 std::string foo{"asdasd"};
 auto index = foo.find("das");
 if (index == std::string::npos) {
      // not found
 } else {
      // index is the index where the substring was found
 }
```